# Does Christianity teach the circumcision of the breath?

Tags: truth

In Zoroastrianism the saying goes 'Good Thoughts, Good Words, Good Deeds.'
The *circumcision of breath* is when "sayings about error" are cut out of ones dialect.

Using a car with a flat tire as an example:

The 'Bad Words' would be 'The car has a flat tire.'
The 'Good Words' would be 'The tire is going to be fixed.'
How does this compare to Christianity?

Is evil(meaning error) speech cut out from the dialect? Or again, 'Is speaking about error cut out from ones dialect?'

Or do they continue to point out:

"This is wrong, this is wrong, and this is broke", like King Thornbush who was cut down and thrown into the crematory.

Comment: This question will be given an opportunity to be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

Christianity has a dedication to truth. Jesus and those who followed him did not shy away from giving the truth about bad situations when they happened and telling of those to come. They did not beat about the bush or employ euphemisms when predicting sufferings, or describe evil as anything but evil.

Jesus followers are commanded to "Let no evil come out of your mouth" (Ephesians 4:29) but it does not mean the same as the Zoroastrian teaching.

I know of no Christian group that has practices like the ones you describe.

Comment: Could you clarify, please, when you wrote, "Jesus followers are commanded to "Let no evil come out of your mouth " but it does not mean that." Surely if Christians have such a command in the Bible, it DOES mean that? A scripture reference for that would be helpful.

Comment: @Anne I meant that the command does not mean the same as the Zoroastrian teaching. I've added a reference and made that clear.

Comment: Excellent. It is now clear! Appreciated.

Comment: "positive confession" -- I think some charismatics / word of faith / prosperity groups do avoid talking about evil in an extreme way. I consider focusing on bad things very unwise. "Don't call your kids stupid", for example -- better said as "encourage kids to value their intelligence" perhaps. Not explicitly Christian maybe, but part of our "be nice" policy. Also, I think Christians ought to avoid  a lot of discussion about erroneous beliefs, even if everything they say is true.

Answer (score 2):

Christianity highly values truthfulness, and so anything that you say that is true is likely to be a good thing to say. To Christianity, if the tire is actually flat, then it's not an error to say so. It would be an error to say otherwise.

Now you can say true things in a demeaning way, which isn't good, and you can say incidental truths while omitting a major truth, which may be deceptive and bad. But for an emotionally neutral statement like "the car has a flat tire", as long as that's actually true, then it's probably a good thing to say. Saying "the tire will be fixed" is no better nor worse, but if you haven't actually made concrete plans to fix it then it could be deceptive and therefore wrong.

Truth matters, but not the precise wording. What matters far more is how our words impact other people. Everything we do and say should build up others.

> Instead, **speaking the truth in love**, we will grow to become in every respect the mature body of him who is the head, that is, Christ. (Eph 4:15 NIV)

Answer (score 2):

God speaks of the need for "the circumcision of the heart" of those to worship Him:

> “And the LORD your God will circumcise your heart and the heart of your offspring, so that you will love the LORD your God with all your heart and with all your soul, that you may live” (Deuteronomy 30:6).

Physical circumcision was a sign of Israel’s covenant with God; circumcision of the heart, therefore, would indicate Israel’s being set apart to love God fully, inside and out.

Jesus himself warned against the dangers of careless words, that what comes out of our mouths comes from our hearts, from our innermost thoughts. Such things defile a person.  Jesus said this in Matthew 12:34-37:

> "You brood of vipers, how can you who are evil say anything good? Forout ofthe overflow of the heart the mouth speaks. The good man brings good things out of the good stored up in him, and the evil man brings evilthings out of the evilstored up in him. But I tell you that men will have to give account on the day of judgement for every careless word they have spoken. For by your words you will be acquitted, and by yourwords you will be condemned."

What comes out of our mouth reflects upon our innermost thoughts and desires.  Therefore we must guard our tongue, lest it defiles us.  That is why Christians need the circumcision of their hearts, so that they may worship God in spirit and in truth.